# How to do email and phone validation in wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

**models.py**

```
class PartnerFormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey(
        'PartnerPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='form_fields',
    )


class PartnerPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    template = "resources/partner_form.html"
    # This is the default path.
    # If ignored, Wagtail adds _landing.html to your template name
    landing_page_template = "resources/partner_form_thankyou.html"

    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label='Form Fields'),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text'),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel("subject"),
        ], heading="Email Settings"),
    ]  
    def get_form_fields(self):
        return self.custom_form_fields.all()
```

**partnerform.html**

```
<section class="partner-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 class="text-center font-weight-bolder">Become a <span style=" color: #f98439;">Domitos</span> partner now!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 mt-4">
        <div class="card p-5 shadow">
          <form id="partnerForm" action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                                        
                {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ field.label_tag }}
                  {% render_field field class+="form-control" placeholder+=field.help_text %}
                 
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group mx-4 mt-4 mb-0">
              <button type="submit" class="btn text-white w-100 p-3">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How to validate email and phone in html.
When i enter something in email it should not submit i want to display enter valid email address and valid phone number
How to do this in wagtail please help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the RegexValidator object, here is a sample I wrote to validate a timeZone entry:

```
    timezone = models.TextField(
        max_length=25,
        help_text="Examples: US/Pacific, America/Los_Angeles, Etc/UTC",
        default='Etc/UTC',
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex = r'^(\w+\/?\w+)$',
                message ='Examples: US/Pacific, America/Los_Angeles, Etc/UTC',
                code='invalid_tz'
            )
        ]
    )
```

You can plug in formatting code such as [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex) in the `regex=` line of your models.py. Email is perhaps a bit more tricky; kindly reference [this article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for samples and possible pitfalls.

Comment: In models.py I done wagtail form fields not done separate form fields then how to do this in models.. Please help

Comment: I read this: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html#form-builder-usage to mean that you need to use separate form fields if you want validation on individual fields: "wagtailforms is not a replacement for Django’s form support. It is designed as a way for page authors to build general-purpose data collection forms without having to write code.

Comment: It is suggested in the above article to look at https://github.com/gasman/wagtail-form-example/ as well; maybe that can give you an insight as to how to break out your fields to perform validation. Of course an entire form can be checked for .isvalid after POST, but I'm pretty sure you're looking for something a bit more in the line of a "Responsive UI" ...

Comment: Ok thank you..How to do separate form fields in wagtail please help

Comment: One more link to look at: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html (you may have patterned your page around these examples).

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/71597/django.core.validators.RegexValidator shows how to use this method. I recommend any or all of the tutorials on https://learnwagtail.com/tutorials/custom-streamfield-field-validation/ but this one will show you how to add stream validation. You may want to review the distinction between validation in the admin pages (my example above) and catching validation errors by the user in completing any wagtail forms and fields therein.

Comment: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#adding-a-custom-field-type is a bit more advanced but will work fine to extend your email and phone # form fields. Or, you may wish to add validation in the HTML template, similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern

Comment: Can you please vote up my answer if you think I've given you the solution you were seeking?

Comment: It is not working in my project

Comment: I sent you quite a few links, did you find no ideas in any of them?